# 500 Internal Server Error installing codeigniter on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, ubuntu-11.10

I have developed my codeigniter project on windows, now I am putting it on the server which is Ubuntu 11.10
I put my root folder in

> var/www

when I access my localhost through the web browser it displays the login page correctly, but when I try to log in, it displays

> 500 Internal Server Error

when I look at my /var/log/apache2/error.log
 it displays the following:

> [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Any idea of what may have made this, and how to solve this problem???
Thanks in advance

Comment: The error gives you your next action to debug the problem. Change your loglevel directive to debug and it will show you where you are bouncing between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem has been solved, but I really don't know why?!!
what I did is that I created a new folder in the var/www and put my root folder in it, so the full path of my application looked like that:

> var/www/myapplications/applicationRoot

then I made some changes to the file

> /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

I set the "DocumentRoot" to

> var/www/myapplications/applicationRoot

and the "Directory" to the same

> var/www/myapplications/applicationRoot

then I tried to access the application from my web browser on using

> localhost

and it displayed the log in page nicely, then when I logged in it worked just fine without any errors

Answer (score 0):

Check your .htaccess file(if you have one) in the CodeIgniter directory root. Is there a RewriteBase directive used in that file or somewhere else? Is it configured correctly? Sharing the .htaccess file if there is one could help to locate your problem.

Comment: I don have a .htaccess file in the ubuntu project root folder, but I used to have it on windows, should I have one????

Comment: Not necessarily. I would check the /etc/apache2/conf.d/apache.conf file and search for <Directory "something/something"> and DocumentRoot "directory/subdir" and see if they look ok. Also check vhost config. The file is probably specified in the httpd.conf like this:
# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: the apache.conf file is empty
where can I find the httpd.conf file???
I opened the /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file with gedit and it was empty 
Sorry I am  new to ubuntu so I don know a lot of basics

Comment: Could it be in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf?

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, you might need the same .htaccess file you have on the windows installation... maybe it has some rewrite rules you need...

Comment: I found the apache2.conf file but it doesn have the DocumentRoot or anything, should I uninstall the apachi server and reinstall it again???? maybe the configurations have something wrong?!!!!

Comment: The file that has DocumentRoot is probably somewhere else and is linked from the conf file. I don't think you need re-installing, but here's one guide:
http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-11.10-lamp for installation.
First put the .htaccess to the CodeIgniter project folder root. That might do the trick.

Comment: Also check for any urls or base_urls in codeIgniter's config files(in the config dir), maybe they are redirecting wrong...